# Ping doesnt work as limited user

Tags: windows-7, uac

This is the issue:

All programs works fine in the network. 
A Command line console, elevated with UAC, can make a ping and everything works fine.

A command line, runnning as standar user, says General Failure when you make ping.

We try:

1. Resseting IPv4 and IPv6 stack.
2. Reset WinSock
3. Diable McAfee anti virus

What more should you do?

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: A command line, runnning as standard user, says General Failure when you make ping. Running as administrator works as espected.

Comment: Because ping is important to the standard user in what way?

Comment: Ping should not require elevated permissions. I bet it's your antivirus. Even though you disabled it. Disable it harder.

Comment: maybe it's a virus, never seen something like this.
If you didn't want to format the machine or you have no time to investigare more, I suggest you to give a try to "[runasspc](http://www.robotronic.de/runasspcEn.html)" tool by menas of which I solved many issues with old software.
In your case this would be a workaround, of course.